# script that can delete tr also subtract from total

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a form which adds labor and it's price same time it displays the labor assigned to it on the same page underneath. [image: as you can see in pic.]

What I want is:
when a user clicks on delete, it deletes the table.tr  and subtracts the labor cost from the total value down there in table end.

```
 while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){    
$serial=$serial+1;                  
$Total=$row2["cost"]+$Total;                                       
                       echo  "<tr >
                          <th scope='row'>",$serial,"</th>
                          <td>",$row2["Labor"],"</td>
                          <td>",$row2["type"],"</td>
                          <td id='cost'>",$row2["cost"],"</td>
                          <td><span class='action'><a href='#' id='",$row2["Labor_id"],"'  class='delete' title='Delete'>Delete</a></span></td>
                        </tr>";

 }
                            echo "<tr><td></td><td></td>
                          <th align='right'>Total</th>
                          <th id='total'>",$Total,"</th>
                        </tr>";

 }
```

The Problem is: As you can see total amount is wrong in pic, it should b 3500 but its 3700. As I deleted 200 cost labor from the table. tr deleted but cost not subtracted from the total. How can I do this with one click?

```js
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm(info)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_labor.php",
                data: info,
                success: function () {}
            });

            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: delete_labor.php works fine, it delete row form database.

Comment: You use the same ID for all cost cells.

Comment: you can do this in two ways. 1) for every delete re caliculate total . 2) for delete_labor.php get total after delete

Comment: return the total from php and access it in success function and append it like this using id $('#total').text(result);

Comment: @sasi kanth thats what i want to recalculate after delete click but how? in second option i have to run another query which i dont like to do.

Comment: @ashi do you want to use php or jquery only

Comment: prefer jquery as it will extra burden on server to run two queries.

Comment: try my answer @AshiPashi

Comment: @JYoThI thank you for your response but i don't want to use two queries. interested to done it with jquery

Comment: that's what i done check my below answer ., i did using jquery @AshiPashi

Comment: check below answer once

Comment: @AshiPashi, You should upvote relative answers as well!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) id should be unique so change it to class name `<td class='cost'>",$row2["cost"],"</td>`

2)  After removing **tr** sum the total again using each function

```
 var total=0;
$('.cast').each(function(){ total=total+parseInt($(this).text().trim()); });
$('#total').text(total);
```

Comment: Oh it working as charm
Thank you all and very special thanks to JYoThI

Comment: glad to help you @AshiPashi

Answer (score 0):

At the end of delete_labor.php, you could echo the new cost, then get it back in your success() method.

Answer (score 0):

First, change attribute from  `<td id='cost'>".$row2["cost"]."</td>` to  `<td class='cost'>".$row2["cost"]."</td>`

And I am surprised how the comma works instead of dot!!

You can get the total from delete_labor.php on success and can put it using jquery to the total box.

Another way, Calculate the sum of cost for HTML class 'cost' and update it to the total box.

**EDIT**

```
function get_total(){
        var main_total = 0;
        if($('.cost').length > 0){
           $('.cost').each(function(i){
                main_total += parseInt( $(this).html())
           }); 
        }
        $('#total').html(main_total);
    }
```

And call this function after `$(this).closest("tr").remove();`
So, Your code will be:

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
get_total();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will you please tell me how to code this "Calculate the sum of cost for HTML class 'cost' and update it to the total box."

Comment: yea, sure.. wait for some minutes.. I will update here with the script.

Answer (score 0):

you should sum total again in delete_labor.php after deleting the row and return in response to show it again in the total div.

Answer (score 0):

try below code.just change the patches only

```
   <td id='cost'>",$row2["cost"],"<input type='hidden' class='cost' value='".$row2["cost"]."'/></td>
```

add input type hidden

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_labor.php",
            data: info,
            success: function () {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.cost').each(function(){
  sum += parseFloat($(this).text());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
});
$('#total').text(sum);
}
        });
```

Comment: On success, first you have to remove existing TR from html then you should calculate. in this code, total will remain same as TR is not deleted yet.